# pip not upgrading packages, installs older versions

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am trying to upgrade certain packages installed at the global(root) level at my user level. Whenever i try to upgrade the package with pip, it simply re-installs the already existing version at the user level.
For example,

$pip install boto --user --upgrade
Collecting boto
  Using cached boto-2.42.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: boto
Successfully installed boto-2.9.5

pip downloads boto-2.42 but installs 2.9.5. 
I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated?

I am using pip 8.1.2

reply to @Evert
The output from pip for `pip install boto --user --ignore-installed` is

`Collecting boto
  Using cached boto-2.42.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: boto
Successfully installed boto-2.9.5`

Note, pip collects the most recent package but falls back to the old package when installing. I cant seem to understand why this happens. The above works correctly in my other machines but not this. I even tried re-installing pip but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install boto --user --ignore-installed
```

Comment: @Vicky Weird, as it worked for me. Can you show the output when running pip with these particular options?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force a reinstall of the desired package:

```
pip install --user -U --force-reinstall boto
```